# Is there a reason Ropsten doesn't have the same block gas limit as mainnet?

Tags: ropsten, gas-limit

It appears as though Ropsten still has a limit of 4.7m gas while mainnet is almost 8m.  This makes testing for real-world dapps difficult.

Why is it that ropsten and mainnet are not in alignment with the block gas limit?

Answer (score 3):

Miners determine the block gas limit, so its not a fixed number. So it seems like miners running on Ropsten aren't changing the block gas limit. I believe the Rinkeby block gas limit is at ~7M, so perhaps you can try testing on there? Or you could using ganache-cli and manually set a block gas limit.

Comment: Any idea why miners would choose to not mirror mainnet?

Comment: @NicSzer Nope...

Comment: I think it's just about incentives, a higher gas limit means miners would have to perform more computations in every block - which costs money.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue around the same time of OP's question. Dani from Infura was kind enough to point me at the Ropsten's Gitter channel --

https://gitter.im/ethereum/ropsten

To my delight, soon after I chatted it in Gitter -- of course it could just be a pure coincidence -- Ropsten gas limit was raised to 7M, until it came down to 4.7M a few days ago.

So the point of the story is: Ropsten is still very opaque and unpredictable.

Comment: April 2019: gas limit seems to now be set to [8M](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/block/5422361).