# Not able to deploy contract in testnet(Ropseten)

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, openzeppelin-contracts

I am trying to deploy a crowdsale contract which is build upon [openzeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/tree/release-v2.0.0) while deploying it on geth --dev and ganache it gets deployed perfectly but whenever I am trying to deploy the contract on the testnet I am getting following error.

```
1_deploy.js
===========
Deploying Token Crowdsale:
        Rate                    : 1
        Wallet                  : 0xDc6234d567eBA03B465f519596E679A8d3959935
        Opening Time            : 1539087204
        Closing Time            : 1539238404
        Cap                     : 4000000000000000
        Individual Min Cap      : 1000
        Goal                    : 800000000000000
        Token Address           : 0x3FEc09Fab0dbb7EdaDbD4a4c06908a3Eb846308f
        Token Wallet            : 0xDc6234d567eBA03B465f519596E679A8d3959935

   Deploying 'TokenCrowdsale'
   --------------------------
   > transaction hash:    0xb2f48b6418021476827c8aeeb51762927c319dc74cd10ffaaa8482f06e3dae5c
Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"TokenCrowdsale" -- The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas limit...

    at /home/paradox/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-deployer/src/deployment.js:361:1
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I am passing 8000000 as the gas amount, any leads would be appreciated.

[SourceCode](https://github.com/Paradox-AT/Token-Crowdsale/tree/development)

Answer (score 1):

Ropsten has lower gas limit - around 4.7M and you can't set it yourself, since it's a public testnet. Gas limit value that you put in your settings can't override the blockchain's gas limit. You can try Rinkeby - it has 7693375, check the number at the top of the stats page: https://www.rinkeby.io/#stats

Check this related question: [Is there a reason Ropsten doesn't have the same block gas limit as mainnet?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/44038/is-there-a-reason-ropsten-doesnt-have-the-same-block-gas-limit-as-mainnet)

I tried running your deploy with Ganache v6.1.8, default gas limit `6721975`, but it didn't even deploy the token:

```
truffle migrate --reset --network development
Using network 'development'.

Running migration: 1_deploy.js
Deploying Token:
        Name            : Sportist
        Symbol          : S
        Decimals        : 6
        Cap             : 10000000000000000
  Deploying Token...
  ... undefined
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: Exceeds block gas limit
```

You don't have to inherit every conract in OpenZeppelin's collection, your crowdsale contract is clearly too big:

`contract TokenCrowdsale is AllowanceCrowdsale, RefundableCrowdsale, IndividuallyCappedCrowdsale, StagedCrowdsale`

Nevertheless, when I put the default value, `6700000`, which is, by no coinscidence, less than Ganache's block gas limit, both transactions passed.

Try putting a value less than your target blockchain's limit.

Comment: But according to truffle the gas used is just 2824348 which is less then the limit

Comment: And what does truffle report on successful deploys to the local environment?

Comment: It would just display the addresses

Comment: Well, you can check the actual transaction cost in ganache, UI or CLI.

Comment: Ganache=>
Gas usage: 2824284

Comment: Just tried your deploy locally - looks like it doesn't work when you set gas limit more than that of the blockchain. Put 4M and see what happens!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84268/discussion-between-paradox-and-utgarda).